# Obtener la suma de algunas lineas de un campo ,dependiendo del valor de otro campo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada diarioslineas con dos campos subcuentad_id  e imported,dependiendo del valor que presente el campo subcuentad_id quiero sumar el campo imported.
Es decir que cuando en el campo subcuentad_id aparezca p.ej.el valor 117 quiero sumar los valores que presente el campo imported .
Si hay dos valores en imported y suman 100,lo que quiero es que el resultado sea el siguiente: Resultado = 117->100.00.

Primero recopilo los valores de subcuentad_id que me interesan`

```
$cuentas_id=DB::select( "SELECT  id AS idsubcuenta FROM subcuentas where "
        . "suscriptor_id = $idsuscriptor AND subcuenta>=$min AND subcuenta<=$max");
```

Array con el id de las subcuentas

```
for($i=0;$i<count($cuentas_id);$i++){
        array_push($datos_subcuentas,$cuentas_id[$i]->idsubcuenta);
```

Vuelco el array en los datos que me llegan desde la vista

```
$datos['subcuentas']=$datos_subcuentas;
```

Al intentar sumar no funciona

```
 $cuentas = DiariosLinea::SUM((imported)   WhereIn('subcuentad_id' $datos['subcuentas']));
```

Espero haberme explicado,gracias anticipadas.

Comment: ¿Sería posible añadir el dataset con unos registros de ejemplo con el resultado que te gustaría obtener?

Comment: Para David JP. ,Si te refieres a las tablas que utilizo ,no creo que se pueda, ,si pudiera enviarte las clases,lo intentaría ;pero en la pregunta planteo lo que quería ;de una tabla obtener algunos registros en base a registros obtenidos de otra tabla.

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes enviar las tablas con unos registros de ejemplo? phpMyAdmin, Exportar; y mostrar qué esperas obtener para los registros de ejemplo que nos pases. ¿Dónde encuentras la dificultad? Por favor, ayúdanos a ayudarte

Comment: Para David JP. perdona la insistencia, ya tengo tres ficheros de ejemplo copiados de las tablas Diarios,diarioslineas y subcuentas ¿como los descargo en esta página?

Comment: Deja unos pocos registros de ejemplo, copias y pegas tras editar la pregunta. Recuerda usar Ctrl+k para marcar lo que copies como código y ya podremos replicar tu base de datos. Dinos el resultado que esperas para esos datos

Comment: Genial, he podido replicar tu base de datos perfectamente. Aunque es preferible que modifiques la pregunta las veces que lo necesites, no que respondas para aclarar la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias mil sólo había un registro que coincidiese ,ahora toca verlo en pantalla o imprimirlo y los problemas siguen y casi lo tengo  ,pero para eso se inventó la programación

Comment: Gracias a ti. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615) y no olvides incluir tu respuesta en la pregunta, no te la vayan a cerrar y se pierda la estructura de los datos

Comment: Estupendo,funciona

Answer (score 0):

Me parece entender que estás buscando algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,subcuenta-43e6 subcuentad_id
      FROM copia_subcuentas  
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT subcuentad_id,SUM(imported) total_imported
      FROM copia_diarioslineas
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c2 USING(subcuentad_id);
```

El inconveniente es que únicamente me coincide uno de tus registros de ejemplo, el 43000001. El resto de las cuentas deben de estar codificadas de forma diferente a como has codificado los id. Cambia las cuentas, o los id, y te funcionará correctamente.

Cuentas: 1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 10, 20, 40, 50

Ids:     1, 4, 16, 17, 21, 23

Espero sea lo que estabas buscando. Déjame en los comentarios cualquier duda o discrepancia con respecto a lo que necesitas.

Answer (score -1):

Deberías utilizar INNER JOIN y GROUP BY
Vuelvo a explicar el objetivo,espero que esta vez mejor.
Quiero obtener grupos de registros homogéneos de diariolineas
por ejemplo.el grupo clientes '430' está formado por las cuentas cuyo código empieza por 430
: condicionantes.1)En la tabla subcuentas cada cliente tiene su id 2)en la tabla diarioslineas no aparece el código del cliente sino su id
$desde y $hasta y el grupo de clientes  son valores entrados en la vista que podrian ser 01.01.2019 a 31.12.2019  y 430 p.ej.
el proceso que he seguido ha sido el siguiente.
Las subcuentas que componen el grupo

```
$cuentas_id=DB::select( "SELECT  id AS idsubcuenta, definicion AS 
sub_definicion FROM subcuentas where "
                                           . "suscriptor_id = $idsuscriptor AND subcuenta>=$min AND subcuenta<=$max");
```

//array con las id de las subcuentas

```
for($i=0;$i<count($cuentas_id);$i++){
        array_push($datos_subcuentas,$cuentas_id[$i]->idsubcuenta);
    }
```

//se vuelca en $datos['subcuenta']

```
$datos['subcuentas']=$datos_subcuentas;

$subcuentas=implode(",",$datos['subcuentas']);
```

//Busco en la base de datos los registros que necesito

```
$sumas = DB::select("SELECT b.subcuentad_id AS nombre, "
. "SUM(imported)as debe,"
. "SUM(importeh)as haber  "
. "FROM diarios a INNER JOIN diarioslineas b "
. "ON b.diario_id = a.id "
. "WHERE   a.fecha between '$desde' and '$hasta'"
. "AND a.suscriptor_id=$idsuscriptor "
. "AND b.subcuentad_id IN($subcuentas)"
. "GROUP BY b.subcuentad_id");
```

Adjunto copia de las tablas1)subcuentas

```
  -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: hl90.dinaserver.com:3306
-- Tiempo de generación: 28-04-2020 a las 19:54:06
-- Versión del servidor: 5.5.62-0+deb8u1-log
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.22

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `gesinoldb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `copia_subcuentas`
--

CREATE TABLE `copia_subcuentas` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `suscriptor_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subcuenta` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `definicion` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sumasdebe` decimal(12,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sumashaber` decimal(12,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `copia_subcuentas`
--

INSERT INTO `copia_subcuentas` (`id`, `suscriptor_id`, `subcuenta`, `definicion`, `sumasdebe`, `sumashaber`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 7, '43000001', 'Reparaciones Garcia S.A.', '0', '0', '2019-08-03 16:38:16', '2019-08-03 16:38:16'),
(8, 7, '43000020', 'Industria tornillera s.a.', '0', '0', '2019-08-04 05:17:34', '2019-08-04 05:17:34'),
(10, 7, '43000040', 'Pedro Perez Sociedad en Comandita', '0', '0', '2019-08-31 06:43:37', '2019-08-31 06:43:37'),
(11, 7, '43000050', 'Reparaciones de calderas  sl.', '0', '0', '2019-08-31 06:52:15', '2019-08-31 06:52:15'),
(14, 2, '43000010', 'Juan Garcia s.l.', '0', '0', '2019-09-10 14:12:00', '2019-09-10 14:12:00'),
(24, 7, '70000000', 'Ventas', '0', '0', '2019-12-28 10:24:24', '2019-12-28 10:24:24'),
(25, 7, '47700000', 'Hacienda Pública IVA  Repercutido', '0', '0', '2019-12-28 10:29:50', '2019-12-28 10:29:50'),
(106, 7, '43000005', 'FeliuGraells s.l.', '0', '0', '2020-02-21 10:37:05', '2020-02-21 10:37:05'),
(107, 7, '43000006', 'Reparaciones Roberto y las cabras s.a.', '0', '0', '2020-02-21 10:42:34', '2020-02-21 10:42:34'),
(114, 7, '43000007', 'Hardy Soft ware s.l.', '0', '0', '2020-02-22 17:06:16', '2020-02-22 17:06:16'),
(115, 7, '43000009', 'Talleres del Rio S.A.', '0', '0', '2020-04-19 05:30:25', '2020-04-19 05:30:25'),
(116, 7, '43000010', 'Reparaciones y contratas S.A.', '0', '0', '2020-04-19 06:03:49', '2020-04-19 06:03:49');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `copia_subcuentas`
--
ALTER TABLE `copia_subcuentas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `copia_subcuentas`
--
ALTER TABLE `copia_subcuentas`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=136;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

2)Diarioslineas

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: hl90.dinaserver.com:3306
-- Tiempo de generación: 28-04-2020 a las 19:25:27
-- Versión del servidor: 5.5.62-0+deb8u1-log
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.22

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `gesinoldb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `copia_diarioslineas`
--

CREATE TABLE `copia_diarioslineas` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `suscriptor_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `diario_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subcuentad_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subcuentah_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ejercicio_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `imported` decimal(12,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `importeh` decimal(12,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `concepto` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `extensionconcepto` varchar(350) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `conceptodos` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `extensionconceptodos` varchar(350) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `copia_diarioslineas`
--

INSERT INTO `copia_diarioslineas` (`id`, `suscriptor_id`, `diario_id`, `subcuentad_id`, `subcuentah_id`, `ejercicio_id`, `imported`, `importeh`, `concepto`, `extensionconcepto`, `conceptodos`, `extensionconceptodos`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(5, 7, 3, 4, 6, 43, '25000.00', '400000.00', 28, '2019', 28, '2019', '2020-03-16 08:35:28', '2020-03-16 11:09:11'),
(6, 7, 3, 1, 95, 43, '550000.00', '150000.00', 28, '2019', 28, '2019', '2020-03-16 08:36:43', '2020-03-31 13:25:49'),
(7, 7, 3, 23, 91, 43, '75000.00', '100000.00', 28, '2019', 28, '2019', '2020-03-16 08:37:49', '2020-03-16 08:37:49'),
(8, 7, 5, 0, 19, 43, '0.00', '94.27', 0, '', 14, 'Enero-2019', '2020-03-16 08:39:49', '2020-03-16 08:39:49'),
(9, 7, 5, 0, 18, 43, '0.00', '480.81', 0, '', 14, 'Enero-2019', '2020-03-16 08:40:24', '2020-03-16 08:40:24'),
(11, 7, 5, 16, 21, 43, '1096.25', '893.80', 14, 'Enero2019', 14, 'Enero0-2019', '2020-03-16 08:42:18', '2020-03-16 08:42:18'),
(12, 7, 5, 17, 0, 43, '372.63', '0.00', 14, 'Enero-2019', 0, '', '2020-03-16 08:43:00', '2020-03-16 08:43:00'),
(13, 7, 6, 0, 19, 43, '0.00', '94.27', 0, '', 14, 'Febrero-2019', '2020-03-16 08:43:24', '2020-03-16 09:46:04'),
(14, 7, 6, 0, 18, 43, '0.00', '480.81', 0, '', 14, 'Febrero-2019', '2020-03-16 08:43:24', '2020-03-16 09:46:20'),
(15, 7, 6, 16, 21, 43, '1096.25', '893.80', 14, 'Febrero2019', 14, 'Febrero-2019', '2020-03-16 08:43:24', '2020-03-16 09:46:44'),
(16, 7, 6, 17, 0, 43, '372.63', '0.00', 14, 'Febrero2019', 0, '', '2020-03-16 08:43:25', '2020-03-16 09:47:05'),
(17, 7, 8, 21, 4, 43, '898.80', '898.80', 14, 'Enero 2019', 14, 'Enero-2019', '2020-03-16 09:51:00', '2020-03-16 09:51:00'),
(18, 7, 9, 0, 19, 43, '0.00', '94.27', 0, '', 14, 'Marzo-2019', '2020-03-16 09:51:59', '2020-03-16 09:54:39'),
(19, 7, 9, 0, 18, 43, '0.00', '480.81', 0, '', 14, 'Marzo-2019', '2020-03-16 09:51:59', '2020-03-16 09:54:26'),
(20, 7, 9, 16, 21, 43, '1096.25', '893.80', 14, 'Marzo2019', 14, 'Marzo-2019', '2020-03-16 09:52:00', '2020-03-16 09:53:56'),
(21, 7, 9, 17, 0, 43, '372.63', '0.00', 14, 'Marzo2019', 0, '', '2020-03-16 09:52:00', '2020-03-16 09:54:12'),
(22, 7, 10, 21, 4, 43, '898.80', '898.80', 14, 'febrero 2019', 14, 'febrero 2019', '2020-03-16 10:04:35', '2020-03-16 14:15:23'),
(27, 7, 13, 0, 19, 43, '0.00', '94.27', 0, '', 14, 'Abril-2019', '2020-03-16 10:16:56', '2020-03-16 10:17:49'),
(28, 7, 13, 0, 18, 43, '0.00', '480.81', 0, '', 14, 'Abril-2019', '2020-03-16 10:16:57', '2020-03-16 10:18:08'),
(29, 7, 13, 16, 21, 43, '1096.25', '893.80', 14, 'Abril2019', 14, 'Abril-2019', '2020-03-16 10:16:57', '2020-03-16 10:18:29'),
(30, 7, 13, 17, 0, 43, '372.63', '0.00', 14, 'Abril2019', 0, '', '2020-03-16 10:16:57', '2020-03-16 10:18:43'),
(31, 7, 14, 21, 4, 43, '898.80', '898.80', 14, 'abril 2019', 14, 'abril', '2020-03-16 10:20:22', '2020-03-16 10:20:22'),
(32, 7, 15, 0, 19, 43, '0.00', '94.27', 0, '', 14, 'Mayo-2019', '2020-03-16 10:20:56', '2020-03-16 10:21:41'),
(33, 7, 15, 0, 18, 43, '0.00', '480.81', 0, '', 14, 'Mayo-2019', '2020-03-16 10:20:57', '2020-03-16 10:21:54'),
(34, 7, 15, 16, 21, 43, '1096.25', '893.80', 14, 'Mayo2019', 14, 'Mayo-2019', '2020-03-16 10:20:57', '2020-03-16 10:22:14');
(35, 7, 15, 17, 0, 43, '372.63', '0.00', 14, 'Mayo2019', 0,'' , '2020-03-16 10:20:57', '2020-03-16 10:22:14');


--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `copia_diarioslineas`
--
ALTER TABLE `copia_diarioslineas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `copia_diarioslineas`
--
ALTER TABLE `copia_diarioslineas`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2308;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

3)diarios

```
 -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: hl90.dinaserver.com:3306
-- Tiempo de generación: 28-04-2020 a las 19:39:26
-- Versión del servidor: 5.5.62-0+deb8u1-log
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.22

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `gesinoldb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `copia_diarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `copia_diarios` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ejercicio_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `factura_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `suscriptor_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `numero` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `year` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mes` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `numerofiscal` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `asiento` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `totaldebe` decimal(12,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `totalhaber` decimal(12,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `cuadre` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `cd` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'cuadrado"c",descuadrado"d"',
  `incompleto` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'detector de falta de datos en las lineas',
  `tipo` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 engloba TODO  el diario,general,compras(2) y ventas(1)',
  `subtipo` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(1)cobro de clientes (2) Pago a Proveedores(3)Pago a acreedores',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `copia_diarios`
--

INSERT INTO `copia_diarios` (`id`, `ejercicio_id`, `factura_id`, `suscriptor_id`, `numero`, `year`, `mes`, `fecha`, `numerofiscal`, `asiento`, `totaldebe`, `totalhaber`, `cuadre`, `cd`, `incompleto`, `tipo`, `subtipo`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(3, 43, 0, 7, 1, 19, 1, '2019-01-01', 1, '19010001', '650000.00', '650000.00', '0.00', 'c', '', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 08:32:18', '2020-03-31 13:51:57'),
(5, 43, 0, 7, 2, 19, 1, '2019-01-31', 4, '19010002', '1468.88', '1468.88', '0.00', 'c', 'i', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 08:38:41', '2020-03-31 13:51:57'),
(6, 43, 0, 7, 2, 19, 2, '2019-02-28', 6, '19020002', '1468.88', '1468.88', '0.00', 'c', 'i', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 08:43:23', '2020-03-31 13:51:57'),
(8, 43, 0, 7, 4, 19, 2, '2019-02-01', 5, '19020004', '898.80', '898.80', '0.00', 'c', '', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 09:49:21', '2020-03-31 13:51:57'),
(9, 43, 0, 7, 1, 19, 3, '2019-03-31', 10, '19030001', '1468.88', '1468.88', '0.00', 'c', 'i', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 09:51:58', '2020-03-31 13:51:58'),
(10, 43, 0, 7, 2, 19, 3, '2019-03-01', 9, '19030002', '898.80', '898.80', '0.00', 'c', '', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 10:01:35', '2020-03-31 13:51:58'),
(13, 43, 0, 7, 1, 19, 4, '2019-04-30', 15, '19040001', '1468.88', '1468.88', '0.00', 'c', 'i', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 10:16:56', '2020-03-31 13:51:58'),
(14, 43, 0, 7, 2, 19, 4, '2019-04-01', 13, '19040002', '898.80', '898.80', '0.00', 'c', '', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 10:19:12', '2020-03-31 13:51:58'),
(15, 43, 0, 7, 1, 19, 5, '2019-05-31', 17, '19050001', '1468.88', '1468.88', '0.00', 'c', 'i', 1, NULL, '2020-03-16 10:20:56', '2020-03-31 13:51:58');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `copia_diarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `copia_diarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `copia_diarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `copia_diarios`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=573;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Tiene más pinta de comentario, ¿no?

Comment: 1) Creo que en mi pregunta pongo claramente cual es el objetivo perseguido 2) Depués de plantear una pregunta acostumbro a analizarla y tratar de encontrar la solución

Comment: SI estás buscando dar respuesta a tu propia pregunta, esta respuesta es de muy baja calidad. Procura indicar con más detalle cómo usar este análisis

Comment: Mensaje recibido alto y claro